# wp_enqueue_style doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress

First of all, I tried this and didn't work: "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89494/how-to-enqueue-the-style-using-wp-enqueue-style/89495#89495".

What I want to do is a plugin with a unique page (options page) and I'm trying to insert in head tag a `<link href="my_dir/css/style.css"/>`. The prefix of my plugin is easydm and has in the main file the followingo code:

```
define( 'EASYDM_VERSION', '1.0' );
define( 'EASYDM__MINIMUM_WP_VERSION', '2.1' );
define( 'EASYDM_DIRECTORY_NAME', 'easy-downloader-manager/' );

define( 'EASYDM_ROOT_DIRECTORY', substr( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ), 0, strpos( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ), EASYDM_DIRECTORY_NAME ) ) );

define( 'EASYDM_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'EASYDM_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

define( 'EASYDM_SETTINGS_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'settings/' );
define( 'EASYDM_SETTINGS_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'settings/' );
define( 'EASYDM_SETTINGS_PATH', 'settings/' );

define( 'EASYDM_CSS_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'css/' );
define( 'EASYDM_CSS_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'css/' );
define( 'EASYDM_CSS_PATH', 'css/' );    

require_once EASYDM_SETTINGS_DIR.'easydm-functions.php';

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'easydm_activation');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );
```

My easydm-functions.php has:

```
function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_plugin_directory_uri().'/'.EASYDM_DIRECTORY_NAME.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'style.css' );
}
```

This is my last try, but I tried some other arguments on wp_enqueue_style() function.

Some help?

Thanks

--- editing ---

Here's a possible way to solve. Indeed, I solved partially the problem. Now I need to cut a string which is appended to my link. See that:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219911/enqueue-script-style-plungin-development/219914?noredirect=1#comment322394_219914

--- editing again ---

I found this http://wpcrux.com/wordpress-enqueue-functions-version/ what solve the above new problem... but still not styling my page... I checked if the path is correct, my file is there, is not empty or any error like these.

Any idea?

Comment: view source and actually see what is outputted.

Comment: It's what I'm doing to verify if the link tag is there... that isn't there.

Comment: thats very odd, id put a echo and exit in your function to make sure its running, do you have a cache header or something?

Comment: changed the function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head() to do this:
`echo 'nothing'; exit;`. Nothing happened. So the function isn't beeing called, what is wrong with the call?

Comment: it seems fine (once your not inside a class). There are a couple of possibilities - 1. you are serving cached files or the browser is using cached files (test by putting exit anywhere in your template) 2. something is removing the action you are adding (using global $wp_scripts cycle through and print them out to see if its in there) try changing themes etc..

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!!

The documentation for `wp_enqueue_style` function is clear to say that the second argument nedd to be relative path to the root installation WordPress. But as I viewed many examples in tutorials using full path I ignored it. Now, defining this constant and all previous steps everything runs ok.

`define( 'EASYDM_CSS_PATH' , str_replace( site_url().'/', '', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ).'css/' );`

and in function:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-style', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'style.css', array(), null, 'all' );`

So, if someone is tired out to looking for and don't wanna read this all discussion, the final code is:

```
define( 'EASYDM_CSS_PATH' , str_replace( site_url().'/', '', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ).'css/' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );
```

functions file:

```
function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-style', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'style.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-manager', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'manager.css', array(), null, 'all' );
}
```

Where I add two styles. I really hope this help someone. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you sharing. I meet the same issue when adding some styles and scripts but I think the issue you pointed out should not be the root cause, actually, my problem is I should add it to wp_enqueue_scripts action like below

```html
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','nz_footer_cumstom_func');
```

I tried your solution, I think both could work. I mean wp_enqueue_style() could accept a relative path as well as a full file path.